# H2 Spring-Data - default value doesn't work

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, h2

I'm trying to have a default value for one attribute, when I persist an object in H2 database with no value for this attribute.

Even with the right entity declaration, the default value is not persisted.

I would like to know why and how I can fix it, I isolated the problem in the code below :

- application.properties

  ```
  spring.h2.console.enabled=true
  spring.h2.console.path=/h2
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
  spring.datasource.username=sa
  spring.datasource.password=
  spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
  spring.jpa.show-sql=false
  ```
- Entity

  ```
  package com.h2.H2POC;

  import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;

  import javax.persistence.*;
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "car")
  public class Car {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;

      @Column(name = "company")
      @ColumnDefault(value = "'Toyota'")
      private String company;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "Car{" +
                 "id=" + id +
                 ", company='" + company + '\'' +
                 '}';
      }

      public Long getId() {
          return id;
      }

      public void setId(Long id) {
          this.id = id;
      }

      public String getCompany() {
          return company;
      }

      public void setCompany(String company) {
          this.company = company;
      }
   }
  ```
- Service

  ```
   @Service
   public class CarService {

      @Autowired
      private CarRepository repository;

      @PostConstruct
      public void init(){
        Car car = new Car();
        repository.save(car);
      }

      public List<Car> getCar (){
        return repository.findAll();
      }
   }
  ```

When I look in the logs, I can see that the database is created with the default value for the attribute company.

```
    14:26:03.087 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - drop table car if exists
    14:26:03.087 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table car (id bigint generated by default as identity, company varchar(255) default 'Toyota', primary key (id))
```

This example use these dependencies :

```
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

The version of main dependencies are :

```
   spring-data-jpa:1.11.9.jar
   com.h2database:1.4.196.jar
```

Thank in advance for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Column(name = "company")
@ColumnDefault(value = "'Toyota'")
private String company;
```

Is this the default value you're talking about? If yes, this is not how you add a default value. You can simple do this.

```
private String company = "Toyota";
```

That is if this is what you were trying to do. This may work. But some do something like this:

```
@Column(name = “myColumn”, nullable = false, columnDefinition = “text default Toyota")
```

As for the `columnDefinition = “text default Toyota"` part, I am not quite sure if that's how you write it. It may be `columnDefinition = “String default Toyota"`

Comment: I tested your second proposition :  @Column(name = "company", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text default 'Toyota'") but this doesn't work I have an exception. For the first solution, I knew that I could do something l would like to understand why it doesn't work, I need to take more time and investigate what's wrong with H2. Thanks your help.

Comment: You can see that the create table is similar to the previous answer : 22:03:43.508 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table car (id bigint generated by default as identity, company text default 'Toyota' not null, primary key (id))

Comment: This answers doesn't seem to take account of cases where we are simply using an insert from a migration script or something of that nature. In my experience defaults are not being respected by h2